# SSRS Display Image on Query Result

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I would like to know if its possible to display an image in SSRS depending on the result of a query.

I have a table that looks like this (it is populated from an sql query):

**Name | Age** 

Bob  |   92

Depending on the age I would like to put in a .jpg file so for example if the age is 50 an image called gold.jpg is displayed. Just to note the jpg files are not stored in the database they will be on an external server.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible, you'd have to set the `Visible` property of the Image and then use an expression such as:

```
=IIF(Fields!Age.Value > 50, True, False)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an expression to determine the name of the image to be displayed. The Source property would be "External". For the Value property use a switch statement like this:

```
=switch(
    Fields!Age.Value > 50, "/Images/Gold"
    Fields!Age.Value < 50, "/Images/Silver"
)
```

Adjust the file names, background repeat, and MIME types as needed. Also keep in mind that the image path must be accessible from where the rdl is stored on the server, it won't work when you preview it in your development studio.